# building Matrix "echelon form"

Tags: matrices

given is 
A = $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 & b \\ b & a & b & 0 \\ 0 & b & a & b \\ b & 0 & b & a \end{pmatrix} $

I need the echelon form for this matrix:

Whenever I begin calculating, I end up with an entry like "a/b", which isn't defined for b = 0.
However, I am supposed to name the echelon form for real numbers a, b.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do it by cases. If $b=0$, then the echelon form will be whatever it will be. If $b\neq 0$, then it's whatever you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First switch the last row with 3rd row

Then divide your first Row by a to introduce a leading 1 then  all you need to do is perform operations to make all elements below the leading 1  ZERO .

e.g  after doing 1st step perform $$ R_2 - bR_1 $$ then perform   $$ R_3 - bR_1 $$

Repeat this with remaining rows

Comment: and yea  you have to assume the denominator variable to be non zero  if any appears...

Comment: I'am eager to ask do you notice the symmetry : the main diagonal is same and the corresponding elements above  and below the diagonal are the same

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much. I noticed the symmetry, but I didn't know what to do with this knowledge :D

Comment: If i helped you can  give my answer a like up :)

Comment: This might be of relevance to you  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12220/symmetrize-eigenvectors-of-degenerate-repeated-eigenvalue

Comment: @KevinLiebing   kmkmkmkmkmkmkmkmkmk

Comment: Hi, I already did :) In the end I get the following matrix, is this correct? $\begin{vmatrix} a & b & 0 & b \\ 0 & b & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 2ab-\frac{a^3}{b} & -a^2 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & a^2  \end{vmatrix} $